# How could a woman born without a hymen prove her virginity in Deuteronomy 22?

Tags: deuteronomy, sexuality

> Deuteronomy 22:20 If, however, the charge is true and no proof of the young woman’s virginity can be found, 21she shall be brought to the door of her father’s house and there the men of her town shall stone her to death. She has done an outrageous thing in Israel by being promiscuous while still in her father’s house. You must purge the evil from among you.

There are females who are born without a hymen. How could they prove their virginity in those days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should treat very delicately here (Deut 22:13-30) in view of several things:

- The hymen is not the focus of these regulation - it is the "spread cloth" as described in V17
- Not all men were obsessed about virginity - the purpose of the regulation here is to place a check or limit on male passion and accusation overreach
- Not all women, even those with an intact hymen bleed when it is first penetrated.  This must have also been known to the ancients.  (However, many do bleed.)

Observe the comments of Gill (a bit too detailed and explicit to reproduce here) and the many cautions contained therein.

I regard this law is a similar light as the law about jealously (Num 5:11-31) - its very existence prevented it from being used.

Comment: Well said. Thanks.